# Why doesn't Autofac Log4Net middleware allow me to directly resolve `ILog`?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac, log4net

I have ASP.NET MVC app which was working fine but once I upgraded Autofac and did the change for Log4Net middleware [example](https://docs.autofac.org/en/v7.0.0/examples/log4net.html) it keeps failling if I try to Resolve ILog.

Here is the code:

```
    public class Log4NetMiddleware : IResolveMiddleware
    {
        public PipelinePhase Phase => PipelinePhase.ParameterSelection;

        public void Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action<ResolveRequestContext> next)
        {
            // Add our parameters.
            context.ChangeParameters(context.Parameters.Union(
                new[]
                {
              new ResolvedParameter(
                  (p, i) => p.ParameterType == typeof(ILog),
                  (p, i) => LogManager.GetLogger(p.Member.DeclaringType)
              ),
                }));

            // Continue the resolve.
            next(context);

            // Has an instance been activated?
            if (context.NewInstanceActivated)
            {
                Type instanceType = context.Instance.GetType();

                // Get all the injectable properties to set.
                // If you wanted to ensure the properties were only UNSET properties,
                // here's where you'd do it.
                IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties = instanceType
                    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                    .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(ILog) && p.CanWrite && p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0);

                // Set the properties located.
                foreach (PropertyInfo propToSet in properties)
                {
                    propToSet.SetValue(context.Instance, LogManager.GetLogger(instanceType), null);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public class MiddlewareModule : Autofac.Module
    {
        private readonly IResolveMiddleware middleware;

        public MiddlewareModule(IResolveMiddleware middleware)
        {
            this.middleware = middleware;
        }

        protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistryBuilder componentRegistryBuilder, IComponentRegistration registration)
        {
            // Attach to the registration's pipeline build.
            registration.PipelineBuilding += (sender, pipeline) =>
            {
                // Add our middleware to the pipeline.
                pipeline.Use(middleware);
            };
        }
    }
```

And here is `Global.asax.cs`:

```
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            var loggerMiddlewareModule = new MiddlewareModule(new Log4NetMiddleware());
            builder.RegisterModule(loggerMiddlewareModule);

            IContainer container = builder.Build();
            ILog log = container.Resolve<ILog>(TypedParameter.From(typeof(MvcApplication)));
        }
```

It fails when it tries to resolve ILog:

> The requested service 'log4net.Core.ILogger' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.
>
> See https://autofac.rtfd.io/help/service-not-registered for more info.
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
> Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException: The
> requested service 'log4net.Core.ILogger' has not been registered. To
> avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the
> service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use
> the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.
>
> See https://autofac.rtfd.io/help/service-not-registered for more info.

#Autofac version 7.1.0

So how can I resolve `ILog`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of just telling you the answer, I'm going to walk you through how you could have figured out what's up on your own, and *then* confirm the answer. So stick with me. :)

What we know:

- You added the `Log4NetMiddleware` to your app.
- You're trying to *directly resolve* an `ILog`.

On the documentation page, the description for `Log4NetMiddleware` is:

> Here’s the sample middleware that injects `ILog` parameters based on the type of the component being activated. This sample middleware handles both constructor and property injection.

This should be a big clue. It's middleware described as allowing you to *inject* `ILog` parameters.

But let's look at the actual middleware code. It's always good to know what the code does that you put in your application.

The first thing we see is a block that calls `context.ChangeParameters`. That block is adding a parameter to the set of parameters going into a resolve operation - it's adding an `ILog` parameter that is based on the calling type. This would be the same as doing something like this:

```cs
container.Resolve<SomethingThatLogs>(
  TypedParameter.From(
    LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SomethingThatLogs));
```

If `SomethingThatLogs` (in this example) has a constructor parameter of `ILog`, it'll resolve. That would mean `SomethingThatLogs` would look like...

```cs
public class SomethingThatLogs
{
  public SomethingThatLogs(ILog logger)
  {
  }
}
```

So, that covers constructors. The next block has some similar work going on, but we see that there's reflection looking at properties. Ah! It's going to try to *inject property values of `ILog`*. Cool, so if `SomethingThatLogs` looks like this instead...

```cs
public class SomethingThatLogs
{
  public ILog Logger { get; set; }
}
```

...then the module will find that property and inject *that* for you.

**What else is in that middleware module?**

**Trick question: NOTHING.**

There's nothing else in there. It can inject a constructor parameter or a property value.

Let's back up again and look at what you're trying to do: you're trying to *resolve an `ILog`*, you're not trying to *resolve something with a constructor or property of `ILog`*.

So when the exception tells you that `ILog` is not registered, that's absolutely right.

**You need to register `ILog` if you want to resolve it directly.**

However, **there's not much value in that**. If you're getting a logger directly like that, just use the `LogManager.GetLogger()` call. Why go through DI? It's not adding value. Log4Net does all sorts of caching and management of the logging instances itself, Autofac isn't handling that.

Comment: You are right, at first I was just trying to upgrade Autofac and got too many errors. But then I started to read it well and I understood that it is only to inject into constructors and properties. Thanks for walking me through it deeply.

Comment: I have now another issue which I need help with. We use `FluentMigrator` and I am getting `Unable to resolve service for type 'log4net.ILog' while attempting to activate 'Migrations.Maintenance.BeforeAll.FlushRedisOnVersionUpdate'.` it seems that the middleware cannot resolve log4net.ILog which is injected inside the constructor

Comment: ```public class FlushRedisOnVersionUpdate : ForwardOnlyMigration
{
        private readonly ILog _logger;
        public FlushRedisOnVersionUpdate(
            ILog logger) : base(migrationProcessor)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
}
```

Comment: I would recommend asking a new question with this and include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). StackOverflow is not really set up for _iterating_ over an evolving set of questions. Alternatively, if you want more interactive help, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a good place to check. Unfortunately, while I try to help folks where I can, I don't have free consulting hours to throw around really digging on every issue every individual has. I wish I did have that kind of time. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, I have created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77420066/autofac-unable-to-resolve-service-for-type-log4net-ilog

Comment: is it possible to have a look into the new question please?

Comment: I answer questions as I have time. This isn't a paid support agreement and, as noted, I don't have a bunch of free consulting hours to throw around, which is why Autofac tells so heavily on the community helping the community. I'm sorry I can't help more.